# Finish drawing a polygon by right-clicking, but displaying a menu instead

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am writing a program that will continuously draw a polygon until the user right-clicks. The user can only draw if and only if the user makes a selection in the menu, if the user does not make a selection in the menu, the program will not draw. Up to now, my program has successfully drawn a polygon with the mouse, but the problem is that when I right-click to complete, the program pops up the menu instead of completing the polygon. Now how can I right-click to be able to complete the polygon, here's my program:

```
const int MAX = 100;
float mouseX, mouseY, ListX[MAX], ListY[MAX];
int numPoints = 0, closed = 0, shape = 0;

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        if (closed || numPoints >= MAX - 1)
            numPoints = 0;
        closed = 0;
        ListX[numPoints] = mouseX;
        ListY[numPoints] = mouseY;
        numPoints++;
    }
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        closed = 1;
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (shape == 1)
    {
        if (numPoints)
        {
            glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
            for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
                glVertex2f(ListX[i], ListY[i]);
            if (closed)
                glVertex2f(ListX[0], ListY[0]);
            else
                glVertex2f(mouseX, mouseY);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
    glFlush();
}

void menu(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        shape = 1;
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("");
    gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 480, 0);

    glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Polygon", 1);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(motion);
    
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks to genpfault, I finished the polygon by right-clicking but I don't know how to reattach it so I can re-open the menu.

```
...

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (shape == 1)
    {
        glutDetachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON); // Add this

        ...
    }
    glFlush();
}

void menu(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        shape = 1;
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("");
    gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 480, 0);

    glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Polygon", 1);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouse_move);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a lost mission. According to online glut doc. for [glutMouseFunc](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node50.html): _If a menu is attached to a button for a window, mouse callbacks will not be generated for that button._

Comment: Did `glutDetachMenu()` at the start of the draw, then re-attaching afterward not work?

Comment: @Scheff, If so, what should I do? Because later I will add other options to the menu so that I can draw more shapes.

Comment: @genpfault, I did the same as you and the program finished the polygon by right-clicking but if I want to make the menu reappear by right-clicking, it doesn't work. How do I re-attach the right mouse button to reopen the menu?

Comment: I wasn't aware that the menu is under your control. (I didn't see this part of code.) The hint of @genpfault appears reasonable to me. You have to decide when the right click should be associated to the menu and when to your interaction. In a widget lib., I might involve a modifier key to distinguish this but I haven't experience with glut to tell you whether this possible in glut as well. (I doubt.) Please, remember that glut is rather an toolkit for little experiments than a tool for production. (At least, this was my impression always.)

Comment: @Scheff, I also found his hint reasonable and followed, but the problem is that after finishing the polygon by right-clicking, I don't know how to re-attach it so I can re-open the menu.

Comment: Can someone help me with how to reattach the right button so I can re-open the menu after finishing the polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Capture the return-value from `glutCreateMenu()`, that's the handle for the new menu.
2. Detach the menu in the menu callback via `glutDetachMenu()` and set a bool indicating you're in "add points" mode.
3. If you're in "add points" mode and detect a right-click, set the current menu to the menu handle from #1 via [`glutSetMenu()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node37.html), then re-attach the menu with `glutAttachMenu()`.  Reset the "add points" bool to `false`.

All together:

```cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>

const int MAX = 100;
float mouseX, mouseY, ListX[MAX], ListY[MAX];
int numPoints = 0, closed = 0, shape = 0;

int hMenu = 0;
bool addingPoints = false;

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;

    if( addingPoints )
    {
        if( button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
        {
            if (closed || numPoints >= MAX - 1)
                numPoints = 0;
            closed = 0;
            ListX[numPoints] = mouseX;
            ListY[numPoints] = mouseY;
            numPoints++;
        }
        if( button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
        {
            closed = 1;

            addingPoints = false;
            glutSetMenu(hMenu);
            glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
        }
    }
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if (shape == 1)
    {
        if (numPoints)
        {
            glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
            for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
                glVertex2f(ListX[i], ListY[i]);
            if (closed)
                glVertex2f(ListX[0], ListY[0]);
            else
                glVertex2f(mouseX, mouseY);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void menu(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        numPoints = 0;
        shape = 1;

        addingPoints = true;
        glutDetachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("");

    hMenu = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutSetMenu(hMenu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Polygon", 1);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(motion);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```